# How to get partial polyline from stream trace?

Tags: geometric-network, nhd

I am creating SOE to do stream trace. That works fine. The geometric network only have NHD flowline. The problem is that tracing result return whole flow line. I am wondering if the result only return partial flowline stating from the input point(s) and stop at the ending point or end of flowline.

Comment: What software are you using?  (What is ["SOE"](http://www.acronymfinder.com/SOE.html)?)

Comment: Is NHD the [National Hydrography Dataset](http://nhd.usgs.gov/data.html)?

Comment: I am using ArcGIS. SOE is server object. It is natinal hydralogical dataset. Thanks.

Comment: What's the trace stream that you perform? Do you need partial polyline because you have for example a destination flag in a middle of edge?